# Primefaces datalist bad remove row

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a problem with this solution. I have an object that has x objects and each of them has a list. When I put 3 items in the list and want to delete the middle one, it visually deletes the last one. But if I dump the contents of the list from the bean, the list contains the first and third item. Where is the problem?

If I add an item after deleting it, the deleted one appears with the values entered. The next one added has no values.

```
 <ui:repeat id="creditProducts" var="cP" value="#{ViewBean.z.creditProduct}" varStatus="status">          
<p:dataList id="calculatorOutputList"
                                                    value="#{cP.cO}" var="output"
                                                    type="definition">

                                            <f:facet name="header">

                                                <p:panelGrid columns="5" layout="grid"
                                                             style="border:0px !important; background:none;"
                                                             styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                                                             columnClasses="ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-2">

                                                    <p:outputLabel value="B"/>
                                                    <p:outputLabel value="S"/>
                                                    <p:outputLabel value="S"/>
                                                    <p:outputLabel value="S"/>
                                                    <p:outputLabel value=""/>
                                                </p:panelGrid>
                                            </f:facet>

                                            <p:panelGrid id="cOG" columns="5" layout="grid"
                                                         style="width: 100%; border:0px !important; background:none;"
                                                         styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                                                         columnClasses="ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-2">
                                                <p:inputText id="oB"
                                                                 value="#{output.b}">
                                                </p:inputText>

                                                <p:inputText id="oR"
                                                                 value="#{output.r}">
                                                    <f:convertNumber locale="cs"/>
                                                </p:inputText>

                                                <p:inputText id="outputD"
                                                                 value="#{output.d}">
                                                </p:inputText>

                                                <p:inputText id="outputPt"
                                                                 value="#{output.p}">
                                                </p:inputText>

                                                <p:commandButton immediate="true"
                                                                 update="calculatorOutputList"
                                                                 action="#{ViewBean.removeCalculatorOutpu(creditProduct, output)}"
                                                                 value="#{msg.remove}"/>
                                            </p:panelGrid>
                                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                                <p:commandButton immediate="true"
                                                                 update="calculatorOutputList"
                                                                 action="#{ViewBean.addCalculatorOutput(creditProduct)}"
                                                                 value="#{msg.add}"/>
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:dataList>
</ui:repeat>
```

UPDATE: Still it didn't work.

```
<p:dataList id="calculatorOutputList_#{ViewBean.ind}"
                                                    value="#{cP.cO}" var="output"
                                                    type="definition" emptyMessage="Žádná data">
```

Comment: could you check your <p:datalist> item id for every object. they are most probably same. you need generate ids dynamically and <p:commandButton> `update` also need to change

Comment: I'm not sure if that's enough. The tree is quite long, but: j_idt26:zojTabView:creditProducts:0:calculatorOutputList:0:calculatorOutputGrid next is
j_idt26:zojTabView:creditProducts:0:calculatorOutputList:0:calculatorOutputGrid_content and j_idt26:zojTabView:creditProducts:0:calculatorOutputList:0:oB

Comment: could you generate id dynamically <p:dataList id="calculatorOutputList_#{id}">

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: could you update your answer what you have tried

Comment: Ok, I update question

Comment: you are repeating with this you need assign id depends on ui param <ui:repeat id="creditProducts" var="cP" value="#{ViewBean.z.creditProduct}" varStatus="status">